# Retrieve the id of a select with laravel and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have two tables: role and persons.

In my persons table I have the foreign key 'idrole' of the table: role. I created a drop-down list which retrieves the roles from my table: role

My problem is as follows: I can't get the id of the selected role from the drop-down list

I am a beginner with laravel and ajax. Thank you for your help

Code of my html page :

```html
<span>Name Role: </span>
<select style="width: 200px" class="namerole" id="nom">

    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">-Select-</option>
    @foreach($roles as $role)
        <option value="{{$role->nom}}">{{$role->nom}}</option>
    @endforeach

</select>

<span>Id Role: </span>
<input type="text" class="idrole" id="idrole" disabled>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on('change', '.namerole', function () {

            var role_nom = $(this).val();

            var div = $(this).parent();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '{!!URL::to('findIdRole')!!}',
                data: {'nom':role_nom},
                dataType:'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('success');
                    div.find('.idrole').val(data.id_r);

                    console.log('error');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My function:

```php
public function findIdRole(Request $request){
    $rj=DB::table('role')
        ->select('id_r')
        ->where('nom',$request->nom)
        ->first();
    return response()->json($rj);
}
```

Comment: what do see in the network tab  when you try to debug? any response / error ?

Comment: I made you a screenshot
look at the comment below

Comment: $role->nom this is same for value and display in option. ? and you have error callback in ajax, use that.

Comment: @AhmedSunny whether I take it off or not, that's not the mistake,
I get the text from the drop-down list but once my code calls my findIdRole function, there it doesn't find the id

Comment: try  $request->get('nom') ,

Comment: can you write me the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

use$ request->get('nom') instead of $request->nom ,

i am not sure but probably it is coming as array and also not an object

```
public function findIdRole(Request $request){
    $rj=DB::table('role')
        ->select('id_r')
        ->where('nom',$request->get('nom')) // here is the change
        ->first();
    return response()->json($rj);
}
```

Comment: try to look in network tab or use print_r($request);exit; ans see what you are getting? are you even getting nom or not

Comment: I get this :  findIdRole?nom=admin
so I get the role

Comment: is your route get?. try $_GET['nom']  in print_r and see if you get value, if yes use it instead of $request->nom

Comment: glad it worked. just for future, you can use $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST in frameworks, $request $this->get is same but with framework syntax, so when you get issues with post or get check the request first. 
you can mark answer as accepted, would appriciate